# Solr intermitent failure of replication with no error

Tags: solr

I have an issue with Solr replication.

I have one master and two slaves.

Every so often the replication failes on one on the slaves.

There is no error in the log file, I have upated the settings to record ALL for replication.

The file *replication.properties* is not "updated" (on the Slave that is failing but it is updated on the other Slave) which suggests that the replication did not start, but according to UI replication took place and "Next Run" is counting time to the next replication, but the same time the replication worked for the other Slave. Both Slaves have connection to Master.

Command "**replication?command=details**" displays different index versions between Master and Slave.

If I use the "Replicate now" button to force the replication - it will work fine and the next occurance will be also fine, but after few hours/days it will start to fail again on either of the Slaves.

How can I investigate this issue further?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra CPU and increasing RAM helped this issue, since the upgrade the replication is working fine.